# Trim an observable array during bindings

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have an observable that I will bind in the id of my div.  How can I remove the whitespaces and special character during bindings.

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default" data-bind="foreach:ScheduleClauseArray">
                <div class="panel-heading" >
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-bind="attr: { href : '#' + ScheduleClause.trim()}, text:ScheduleClause">Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="attr: {'id': ScheduleClause.trim()}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It!.. I just need to create a computed observable in my viewmodel and call that computed observable in my bindings

```
setUpViewModel.sanitizeScheduleClause = function (scheduleClause) {  
  var s = scheduleClause.split(' ').join('');
  return s.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
}.bind(setUpViewModel);
```

Here is HTML

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default" data-bind="foreach:ScheduleClauseArray">
                <div class="panel-heading" >
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-bind="attr: { href : '#' + setUpViewModel.sanitizeScheduleClause (ScheduleClause)}, text:ScheduleClause">Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="attr: {'id': setUpViewModel.sanitizeScheduleClause (ScheduleClause)}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a computed observable:

```
self.ScheduleClause = ko.observable("testId");
self.trimmedScheduleClause = ko.computed(function(){
    return $.trim(self.ScheduleClause());
}, self);
```

and then:

```
data-bind="attr: {'id': trimmedScheduleClause}"
```

Comment: $.trim is jquery trim: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/. You have to load jquery to use it. If you don't use jquery, you can replace $.trim with some other code that strips whitespace.

Comment: Knockout provides its own implementation, `ko.utils.stringTrim`.